# How can I connect a Tree class to a Symbol Table class?

Tags: java

```
import java.util.List;



public class Arbol {
    private Nodo raiz;
    private TablaDeSimbolos tablaDeSimbolos;

    public Arbol(Nodo raiz) {
        this.raiz = raiz;
        
    }
    public void recorrer() {
       
        recorrerNodo(raiz);
    }

private void recorrerNodo(Nodo nodo) {
    if (nodo.getValue() == null || nodo.getHijos() == null) {
        return;
    }

        Token t = nodo.getValue();
        switch (t.tipo) {
            // Operadores aritméticos
            case SUMA:
            case RESTA:
            case MULTIPLICACION:
            case DIVISION:
            case MAYOR_QUE:
            case MENOR_QUE:
            case MAYOR_IGUAL:
            case MENOR_IGUAL:
            case IGUAL_IGUAL:
            case DIFERENTE:
            case IGUAL:
                SolverAritmetico solver = new SolverAritmetico(nodo, tablaDeSimbolos);
                Object res = solver.resolver();
                System.out.println(res);
                break;

            case VAR:
                String nombreVariable = nodo.getHijos().get(0).getValue().literal.toString();
                Token valorToken = nodo.getHijos().get(1).getValue();
                Object valor = null;
                if (valorToken.tipo == TipoToken.NUMERO) {
                    valor = Double.parseDouble(valorToken.literal.toString());
                } else if (valorToken.tipo == TipoToken.CADENA) {
                    valor = valorToken.literal.toString();
                }
                tablaDeSimbolos.agregar(nombreVariable, valor);
                break;

            case PRINT:
                Nodo identificadorNode = nodo.getHijos().get(0); // Obtener el nodo hijo que contiene el identificador
                String identificador = identificadorNode.getValue().literal.toString();
                Object valorImpresion = tablaDeSimbolos.obtener(identificador);
                System.out.println(valorImpresion);
                break;

            case WHILE:
                if (nodo.getHijos().size() < 2) {
                    Principal.error(t.posicion, "Faltan operandos para el ciclo while");
                    return;
                }
                Nodo condicionWhile = nodo.getHijos().get(0);
                Nodo cuerpoWhile = nodo.getHijos().get(1);
                SolverAritmetico condicionWhileSolver = new SolverAritmetico(condicionWhile, tablaDeSimbolos);
                boolean whileR = (boolean) condicionWhileSolver.resolver();
                while (whileR) {
                    recorrerNodo(cuerpoWhile);
                    condicionWhileSolver = new SolverAritmetico(condicionWhile, tablaDeSimbolos);
                    whileR = (boolean) condicionWhileSolver.resolver();
                }
                break;

            case FOR:
                if (nodo.getHijos().size() < 4) {
                    Principal.error(t.posicion, "Faltan operandos para el ciclo for");
                    return;
                }
                Nodo inicializacionFor = nodo.getHijos().get(0);
                Nodo condicionFor = nodo.getHijos().get(1);
                Nodo actualizacionFor = nodo.getHijos().get(2);
                Nodo cuerpoFor = nodo.getHijos().get(3);
                recorrerNodo(inicializacionFor);
                SolverAritmetico condicionForSolver = new SolverAritmetico(condicionFor, tablaDeSimbolos);
                boolean forR = (boolean) condicionForSolver.resolver();
                while (forR) {
                    recorrerNodo(cuerpoFor);
                    recorrerNodo(actualizacionFor);
                    condicionForSolver = new SolverAritmetico(condicionFor, tablaDeSimbolos);
                    forR = (boolean) condicionForSolver.resolver();
                }
                break;

            case IF:
                if (nodo.getHijos().size() < 2) {
                    Principal.error(t.posicion, "Faltan operandos para la estructura if");
                    return;
                }
                Nodo condicionIf = nodo.getHijos().get(0);
                Nodo cuerpoIf = nodo.getHijos().get(1);
                SolverAritmetico condicionIfSolver = new SolverAritmetico(condicionIf, tablaDeSimbolos);
                boolean ifR = (boolean) condicionIfSolver.resolver();
                if (ifR) {
                    recorrerNodo(cuerpoIf);
                }
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

        for (Nodo n : nodo.getHijos()) {
            recorrerNodo(n);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        construirCadena(raiz, sb, 0);
        return sb.toString();
    }

    private void construirCadena(Nodo nodo, StringBuilder sb, int nivel) {
    if (nodo == null) {
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < nivel; i++) {
        sb.append("  "); // Espacios para la indentación
    }
    sb.append(nodo.getValue()).append("\n");

    List<Nodo> hijos = nodo.getHijos();
    if (hijos != null) {
        for (Nodo hijo : hijos) {
            construirCadena(hijo, sb, nivel + 1);
        }
    }
}



    

}
```

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class TablaDeSimbolos {

   
    private final static Map<String, Object> values = new HashMap<>();
   

    static boolean existeIdentificador(String identificador) {

       return values.containsKey(identificador);
    }
    static Object obtener(String identificador)
{
    if (values.containsKey(identificador)){
        return  values.get(identificador);
    }
    throw new RuntimeException("Variable no definida '" + identificador + "'.");
}
static void agregar(String identificador ,Object valor){
    values.put(identificador,valor );
}
}
```

I am making a compiler and I am doing the semantic analysis part, I have already made the conversion from infix to postfix. I already generated the abstract syntax tree and when entering the tree method, I can visualize what it generates, but I cannot establish the connection or initialization with the symbol table, since I need to meet the following requirements: The third installment of the final project consists of, given an input code, generating the tree of
Abstract Syntax Tree (AST) and then traverse
said AST in order to interpret it and carry out the pertinent actions.
The interpreter must be able to operate the if, while, and for control structures, as well as the
var and print statements. You must also evaluate arithmetic, relational, and logical operations.

Symbol table:
The code of a class that corresponds to the symbol table was provided. The interpreter must
be able to manipulate said table, through the following actions:
 When, when traversing the AST, they come across a VAR node, it must go to the table of
symbols and register the variable that you are trying to define, if it already exists, it will be
should indicate so with an error message.
 If you try to make use of the value of a variable, you must first access the table of
symbols to verify that said variable exists, if it does not exist it must be indicated with
an error message.
The symbol table must work "globally" for the entire program. imagine the
following situation:

>> var a = 0;
>> print a;

In the previous figure, two sentences were entered through the keyboard, in the first one the
variable a, which is entered into the symbol table. In the second statement, the table is accessed
of symbols to retrieve the value of a.

I tried implementing singleton to make the symbol table global and be able to access it, but even so, when I want to print what the symbol table contains, it does not do so.

Comment: It would help to have some java docs in the code itself to increase the chances of folks answering this. The code without any docs makes it hard to follow (you can perhaps move the text below & use it)